# How to plan and test (for) bad connectivity

Tags: c#, .net, sockets

I have created an application which uses a System.Net.Sockets.Socket and reads data asynchronously. Everything works great and has been working great for a while.

Recently, however, my ISP has been very unreliable and I am losing packets or there are huge delays, and pretty much whatever one could imagine.

Is there a way to simulate a bad ISP, so that I can debug under these circumstances as well as 'correct' any obvious problems.

Comment: I am using TCP, although I am looking to switch to UDP eventually

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[VMWare Teams](http://www.vmware.com/support/ws55/doc/ws_team.html) can emulate slow network speeds and packet loss.

Answer (score 0):

I've not tried this, but you could give Speed Limiter ( http://www.soft32.com/download_80223.html ) a shot. From the site:

"Speed Limiter can simulate slow TCP/IP connections. Use Speed Limiter for example to see how long a website have to load on slow connections. Or test your software with slow TCP/IP connections."

Comment: I want to simulate an unreliable connection, not a slow one.